# Android permanent GPS request

Tags: android, gps

I've been getting trouble at placing a good architecture on my app. It needs to get regular GPS updates (I've created the listener, with right parameters for update frequency).

The problem arises when I try to figure where to set up that code: it should be placed in something like a service, because I want to keep it in background, but it seems that services keeps running on main thread. Additionally, I need to be sure that, even if the app is killed, I don't lose GPS updates.

So, the solutions seems to be the following:

1. Service (can it be run on background?) that registers a listener, and keeps running. Some kind of alarm that sets up this service if it's killed
2. An alarm, that fires every X minutes, register the listener, waits for its response, and shuts down waiting for next signal

Which strategy should be better? Is there any good practice in android when I need to do long tasks (like receiving periodical data indefinitely)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can run your service in its own process. 
See "Service Process" in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

You arrange an extra process for your service in the manifest, see the `android:process` attribut of the `service` tag in 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: It ensures that if my service do some intensive stuff, it will not show the dialog of "This app is not responding. Do you want to close it?"?